# Formula for Entries of Rotation Matrix in k-Dimensions

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, rotations

The rotation matrix for 2d and 3d using solely trigonometric functions are respectively given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions) and are well known. In both, they use trigonometric functions. Is there a iterative formula, A(row, column, dimension), that gives the entries of a rotation matrix in arbitrary dimensions (using trigonometric functions, not quaternions or any other things.)?

Comment: This may be related to this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566278/calculating-the-analogue-of-euler-angles-tait-bryan-angles-for-dimensions-3

Comment: @Gribouillis It is related.

Answer (score 0):

According to your first reference, rotation matrices can be characterized as [orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) with determinant 1; that is, a square matrix $R$ is a rotation matrix if and only if $R^T=R^{-1}$ and $\det R = 1$. It is known, that the effect of any ($n$-dimensional) orthogonal matrix separates into independent actions on orthogonal two-dimensional subspaces. That is, if $Q$ is special orthogonal then one can always find an orthogonal matrix $P$, a (rotational) change of basis, that brings $Q$ into block diagonal form, see details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Canonical_form).